# Conditional clauses and serial commas

Tags: grammar, commas, clauses

> Once the coins have passed their expiry date, they will no longer be valid, and will not be reissued.

Is this an example of a zero conditional sentence?
Is the last comma acceptable?
Is the tense correct? Should it be 'will' or 'are'?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this an example of a zero conditional sentence?

For it to be a zero conditional sentence, it needs the 'if' clause with the present simple tense. A zero conditional sentence is used only when the result will always happen. In this case, it is not a general fact, maybe some country/institution still accepts the coins with an expiry date, or do not have an expiry date. Even if you have a context in which an institution/country is giving this statement, it cannot be a zero conditional sentence.

Zero conditional sentences would be something like, "if he keeps eating sugar, he will get fat".

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer. Have you got a reference for this that lists all the numbered conditionals as they are taught in your schools? And which schools are those? Numbered conditionals are not taught in American schools (don't know about British or Australian) and the terms mean nothing to American grammarians.